# How to prevent Rails locale=xx in URL (disable)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, internationalization

This is what I have:

- Rails 4
- I18n with three locales enabled.
- One of these three is default and does not use scopes in routes (thus it works exactly I want).
- default_url_options enabled and I am aware of it and what exactly it does..

Now, the challenge is to avoid (disable) 'identical content' URL generation. For example:

http://www.bla-bla-bla.com/en/super-duper-post-1

and

http://www.bla-bla-bla.com/super-duper-post-1?locale=en

both having the same content (this is obvious as of i18n and routes logic).

As far as I understood this is due to scoping of '(:locale)' in routes.rb..

So I'd like to disable ?locale URL at all and stick with /(:locale) format.. 
The only default locale works exactly as I need at the moment as I don't use (:locale) scope for it.

You probably want to say me that it is time wasting and you won't need to do anything with it, but it's not. I am pedant, really want to make all things clear. It is really annoying to have same content indexed by robots.. don't tell me to disallow indexing in robots.txt, please ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code in your ``routes.rb``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is what I have within routes (routes.rb):

```
  devise_for :users
  post '/feedbacks' => 'feedback#create'
  resources :careers
  resources :articles, :path => "blog"
  resources :tag

  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|cs/ do
    root 'pages#home'
    resources :articles, :path => "blog"
    resources :tag
  end
```

This is what I have within locale configuration (application.rb):

```
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
```

Also I have

```
 before_action :set_i18n_locale
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected


def set_i18n_locale
  if params[:locale]
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || :ru
    @root = '/' + params[:locale]
  else 
    I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
    @root = '/'
  end
end
def default_url_options(options = {})
  { :locale => ((I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale) ? nil : I18n.locale)  }
end
```

All things that are belongs to scope in routes use en and cs locales, the one which is not under scope is default one and is ru locale.

I guess all things are setup pretty straight.

I want to disable ?locale= behaviour and stick with doman.com/locale/slug..